# Unexpected values in recursive loop

Tags: javascript

I have a recursive loop which for this question I've simplified to the following:

```js
const move = (gameGrid) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.2) return false;

    let newGameGrid = [...gameGrid];
    return newGameGrid;
}

const play = (initGrid) => {
    for (let player1Move=0; player1Move<9; player1Move++) {
        grid1 = move(initGrid);

        if (!grid1) continue;

        for (let player2Move=0; player2Move<9; player2Move++) {
            // Why is grid1 sometimes false here???
            grid2 = move(grid1);

            if (!grid2) continue;
            play(grid2);
        }
    }
}

play([])
```

What you'll notice if you run this is that sometimes in the second `play()` loop the call to `move(grid1)` fails at `[...gameGrid]` because `grid1` is false. However, this should be impossible because before the second loop executes `grid1` is checked for a false value.

Any ideas what I'm missing here? I'm guessing grid1 is being overwritten but I'm not sure how or where.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something but doesn't `if (!grid1) continue;` basically state: `if grid1 is false, continue to the for loop`?

Comment: @imvain2 it's skipping the current iteration but continues looping. Similar to how `break;` also stops the current iteration but with `continue` you do still stay in the loop.

Comment: @imvain2 I had to look it up too: [`continue` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you tring to achieve, but looks as you **haven't defined `grid1` and `grid2` in scope** they are shared between multiple calls in **global scope** during recursive function calls. Use 'let' or 'const` to define both variables in scope and that will fix issue you mentioned.

```js
const move = (gameGrid) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.2) return false;

  let newGameGrid = [...gameGrid];
  return newGameGrid;
}

const play = (initGrid) => {
  for (let player1Move = 0; player1Move < 9; player1Move++) {
    let grid1 = move(initGrid);

    if (!grid1) continue;

    for (let player2Move = 0; player2Move < 9; player2Move++) {
      // Why is grid1 sometimes false here???
      let grid2 = move(grid1);

      if (!grid2) continue;
      play(grid2);
    }
  }
}

play([])
```

Comment: How embarrassing, I have been looking at this for over an hour. How the hell did I miss that. Thank you.